# How do I reduce screen brightness and activate keyboard on Chromebook for Puppy Linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard, touchpad, brightness

I am trying to get into Linux. I installed Puppy Linux on a USB drive and have succesfully booted on a Chromebook (specifically: https://www.notebookcheck.net/Acer-Chromebook-11-N7-C731-C8VE.206948.0.html). I downloaded Puppy Linux, because I thought it would be the best place to start, for my experience level (which is basically zero) but have had a wretched, wretched time. The screen's backlight will not reduce. I have tried using the built-in application "RedShift" and their gamma adjustment on start-up, but it has not worked. Who didn't think to add a backlight adjustment feature, instead a color adjustment feature for "brightness"? Regardless, my keyboard doesn't work either. My touchpad, barely, works - as in - the sensitivity is atrocious. I tried changing the keyboard and touchpad settings, to no avail. I even made sure the keyboard module was set to "chromebook", but no difference.
All I want to be able to do is look at the screen without getting a piercing headache, because I am prone to those. Thankfully, I still have a separate PC, to look at. I want my keyboard and mouse to work, so I can browse and learn Linux gradually, slowly. I even tried going to the Puppy Linux forums, but had trouble there "registering" for an account, to even begin asking questions! "Email domain has no valid MX record". I feel like the people must hate me for existing, as this was not made for "grandpas", as I can't even get the basic functions to perform.

Comment: Ten years or so ago I tried Puppy Linux as a new user to Linux. It was not an easy distribution to start with at that time. I cannot say what it’s like today because I haven’t used it recently. At the same time I tried Ubuntu and that just worked. Your chromebook is obviously not that powerful and is probably the reason you were attracted to Puppy. I’d recommend lubuntu. You should have the best of Ubuntu with less stress on your hardware.

Comment: Thank you. I will consider this.